# How to format json file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have json file like this, How can I write a code to format above json file that
looks same as below

```
{'alerts': [{'id': 573983, 'version': 2, 'createdOn': 1615530258000, 'modifiedOn': 
1615530763000, 'type': 'EVENT', 'name': '[IBM]: Usage Tier Changed', 'description': 'A host 
changed to a higher usage tier', 'enabled': True, 'criteria': {'text': 'Hosts in tier have 
increased', 'source': None, 'severity': None, 'query': None, 'scope': None}, 'severity': 4, 
'timespan': 600, 'customNotification': {'titleTemplate': '{{__alert_name__}} is 
{{__alert_status__}}', 'useNewTemplate': True}, 'notificationCount': 0, 'teamId': 36050, 
'autoCreated': True, 'rateOfChange': False, 'reNotifyMinutes': 30, 'reNotify': False, 
'invalidMetrics': [], 'groupName': 'default', 'valid': True, 'severityLabel': 'LOW', 
'condition': 'count(customEvent) > 0', 'customerId': 45992, 'lastCheckTimeInMs': 
1638964620000}, {'id': 576757, 'version': 1, 'createdOn': 1616520901000, 'modifiedOn': 
1616520901000, 'type': 'MANUAL', 'name': 'Root volume disk usage warning', 'description': 
'Root volume disk usage warning', 'enabled': False, 'severity': 4, 'timespan': 300, 
'customNotification': {'titleTemplate': '{{__alert_name__}} is {{__alert_status__}} on 
host.mac = {{host.mac}}', 'useNewTemplate': True}, 'notificationCount': 0, 'teamId': 36050, 
'autoCreated': True, 'rateOfChange': False, 'reNotifyMinutes': 30, 'reNotify': False, 
'invalidMetrics': [], 'groupName': 'default', 'valid': True, 'severityLabel': 'LOW', 
'segmentBy': ['host.mac'], 'segmentCondition': {'type': 'ANY'}, 'condition': 
'avg(avg(fs.root.used.percent)) > 80', 'customerId': 45992}]}
```

How can I write a code to format above json file that
looks same as below
I have json file like this, How can I write a code to format above json file that
looks same as below

```
{
   "alerts":[
      {
         "id":573983,
         "version":2,
         "createdOn":1615530258000,
         "modifiedOn":1615530763000,
         "type":"EVENT",
         "name":"[IBM]: Usage Tier Changed",
         "description":"A host changed to a higher usage tier",
         "enabled":true,
         "criteria":{
            "text":"Hosts in tier have increased",
            "source":"None",
            "severity":"None",
            "query":"None",
            "scope":"None"
         },
         "severity":4,
         "timespan":600,
         "customNotification":{
            "titleTemplate":"{{__alert_name__}} is {{__alert_status__}}",
            "useNewTemplate":true
         },
         "notificationCount":0,
         "teamId":36050,
         "autoCreated":true,
         "rateOfChange":false,
         "reNotifyMinutes":30,
         "reNotify":false,
         "invalidMetrics":[
            
         ],
         "groupName":"default",
         "valid":true,
         "severityLabel":"LOW",
         "condition":"count(customEvent) > 0",
         "customerId":45992,
         "lastCheckTimeInMs":1638964620000
      },
      {
         "id":576757,
         "version":1,
         "createdOn":1616520901000,
         "modifiedOn":1616520901000,
         "type":"MANUAL",
         "name":"Root volume disk usage warning",
         "description":"Root volume disk usage warning",
         "enabled":false,
         "severity":4,
         "timespan":300,
         "customNotification":{
            "titleTemplate":"{{__alert_name__}} is {{__alert_status__}} on host.mac = {{host.mac}}",
            "useNewTemplate":true
         },
         "notificationCount":0,
         "teamId":36050,
         "autoCreated":true,
         "rateOfChange":false,
         "reNotifyMinutes":30,
         "reNotify":false,
         "invalidMetrics":[
            
         ],
         "groupName":"default",
         "valid":true,
         "severityLabel":"LOW",
         "segmentBy":[
            "host.mac"
         ],
         "segmentCondition":{
            "type":"ANY"
         },
         "condition":"avg(avg(fs.root.used.percent)) > 80",
         "customerId":45992
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I write a code to format above json file that
looks same as below

Answer (score 1):

Use Json and pprint libs

```py
import json
import pprint
json_data = None
with open('file_name.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
prettyjson = pprint.pprint(json_data)
```

Comment: I have written below code getting error
    import json
    import pprint
    json_data = None
    with open('Alerts.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    prettyjson = pprint.pprint(json_data)

      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "format.py", line 6, in <module>
      json_data = json.loads(data)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
       json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: 
      line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
import pprint
json_data = '';
pprint.pprint(json_data);
```